# VSCODE integrated terminal and gcloud commands

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, gcloud

I have installed git and vscode on my machine, but once I started using bash as the default terminal in vscode some commands give me the output "the terminal process "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe '-- login', '-c'" followed by the instruction to execute... commonly when dealing with "gcloud","PubSub Emulator" and "BigTable Emulator" commands is there any modification missing in the ide?

I already checked my environment variables and everything seems to be in order.

my settings of the integrated terminal is as follows:

```
{
   "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows":{
      "Bash":{
         "path":"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"
      }
   },
   "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows":"Bash"
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the full error you are getting?

Comment: sure! 
"The terminal process "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe '-- login', '-c', 'gcloud beta emulators bigtable start --host-port localhost:8086'" terminated with exit code:49